# Qgis3 APIbreak : QgsFeedback instead QProgressDialog while using QgsRasterCalculator

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, raster-calculator

I upgraded my Qgis to 3.0.1 and I try to upgrade some of the plugins I wrote.

I have a plugin which uses GDAL/rastercalculator from several raster layers to get new information.

With Qgis2 api it was easy to add a progress dialog to the process :

```
progress = QProgressDialog("Calcul", "Annuler", 0, 100,self.dockwidget)
calc = QgsRasterCalculator(formula, output_path, 'GTiff', map.extent(), map.width(), map.height(), entries)
calc.processCalculation(progress)
```

Qgis3 api uses a QgsFeedback instead of a QProgressDialog (see https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html).

Does anyone know how to use `QgsFeedback` to create a progress bar ? I couldn't find any example.

Comment: Great you found it, did you know you can make an answer to your own question? That will help others in the same situation to discover this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it :

```
feedback = QgsFeedback(self.dockwidget)
progress = QProgressDialog("Processing...","Cancel", 0, 100, self.dockwidget)
progress.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModal)
progress.setMinimumDuration(500)
feedback.progressChanged.connect(progress.setValue)
progress.show()
calc = QgsRasterCalculator( formula, output_path, 'GTiff', slope_map.extent(), slope_map.width(), slope_map.height(), entries)
calc.processCalculation(feedback)
```

Now it works.

Comment: This is the answer the OP found, but he added to the question body.